# Installing git & gitlab on debian wheezy

Tags: git, debian, gitlab

I'm using debian wheezy and would like to install git & gitlab on my server

I follow this tutoriel https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md up to the step "install gems" where when I do

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

I get this

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.4)

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:13:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Of course, I tried

gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'

I tried it in like that, with the user git, and in root

Normal user return failed (no autorisation), but git and root work, and even after that, I get the exact same error message

Anyone ever managed to install it?

Or have some experience with ruby and know what could be wrong

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Should fix it :). I've just done it.